# Widgets and the MediaStore

Tags: java, android, widget

I am new to coding in java and I am trying to access the mediastore images from the collectionWidgetViewFactory but when i'm testing it, I am getting a permission error. I do not have an activity so there is no way for me to use the ActivityCompat.requestPermission method. Is there a way to get the permissions necessary to access the Mediastore without an activity?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you must create a activity for asking permissions and then process to the widget and do remaining stuff.

Good idea would be creating settings screen for your widget which will popup for the very first time your app installs and get the permission from user.